# We inadvertently changed our ssl certificate from https://www to https://, and Google remembers the old way?

Tags: ssl-certificate, redirect, https, google

We launched an ecommerce site a while back and got an ssl certificate for https://www.mysite.com.  The site was abandoned for a while, and then recently resurrected.  We got a new ssl certificate, but this time it was for https://mysite.com.  Now, when people find the site on Google, the url is for https://www.mysite.com, and gives an untrusted site warning.

After some digging I've learned that I can't just redirect https://www.mysite.com to https://mysite.com without having a different ssl certificate for the www version.  Is there a way I can correct this problem without having to buy another certificate?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use [Google's tools to remove a site from their index](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663427). Even if you did get a second certificate, the cache mix-up will be confusing to customers and developers alike. I think the most thorough solution is to remove the "bad" URL from Google's cache.

Comment: Few people will have gone to the site at this point, so this may fully solve the problem.

Comment: @dvcolgan Even if it's not the total solution, I think it has to be at least a large part of it. Then, of course, you'll want to check Bing and Yahoo to see what they've cached and how to go about removing any traces.